# Bootstrap 3 - Grid on several dedices looks ugly with diffent contents height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I played a bit with bootrap 3 grid system and several devices. You can copy my code in your editor for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'> </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px; height:50px;">BOX 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px;">BOX 2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px;">BOX 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px;">BOX 4</div>
   </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine. When I make the browser smaler I will get first 2 cols and then 1 col.

The problem is, when I have 2 col, the output in the browser looks ugly because the content in box 1 is not as height as the other boxes. This creates a big space in the output.

Screen: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a920zcld0

When all contents have the same height, it looks very good.

I will use this technic for category listing with images. These images do not have the same height and it looks very ugly. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `clearfix` class to fix this.

Here's the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'> </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px; height:50px;">BOX 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px;">BOX 2</div>
   </div>

   <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>

   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px;">BOX 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <div style="border:1px solid red; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:100px;">BOX 4</div>
   </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see I added the fix after box 2. The `visible-xx` class is added the viewports where it is not displaying correctly.

You can read more about it on the bootstrap page

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Hope that helps!

Comment: This helps me alot. I did not see this. Thanks alot.